# Looping though arrays dealing with null values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array myArray

```
Array ([0] =>(
         Number => 02348
         Food => Array (
             [0] => orange
             [1] => apple
             [2] => plum )
         State => Array (
             [0] => california
             [1] => texas
             [2] => arizona )
        Status => good )
       [1] =>(
         Number => 34
         Food => Array (
             [0] => grape
             [1] => bannana
             [2] => tomato )
        Status => rotten )
        [2] =>(
         Number => 007
         Food => Array (
             [0] => oranges
             [1] => apples
             [2] => plums )
         State => Array (
             [0] => ohio
             [1] => utah
             [2] => vermont )
        Status => good )
```

I am looping though my array and then grabbing the fields i need.

```
for($index=0; $index < count($myArray); $index++){
   $food = array_values(array_filter($myArray[$index]["Food"]));
   $states = array_values(array_filter($myArray[$index]["State"]));
```

For the $states line i get an error of

```
Notice: Undefined index: State 
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

As you can see in my array State may not always be present, is there a way to get around this. Also there is a large amount of data is being pulled dynamically and it would be difficult to change the structure of the array.
How can i loop though my array ignoring nulls but still keeping the place of State. For example

```
State => Array (
         [0] => ohio
         [1] => utah
         [2] => vermont )
```

would still be mapped to the [2], and not shifted to [1].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: use isset($myArray[$index]["State"])

Comment: Fix one warning, and the other follows. Just check if the index is set before you use it.

Comment: Could you please clarify this phrase: "but still keeping the place of State".Are you probably doing something with states and food afterwards - collecting in the array or something?

Comment: Some indexes dont exist because some are null so the value for States in this case would be 2. The value for food would be 3.

Comment: @Vladislav i would like to keep the array where it is for example State => Array (
         [0] => ohio
         [1] => utah
         [2] => vermont ) would still be mapped to the 2nd array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$states = array_values(array_filter($myArray[$index]["State"]));
```

Using the above example from your code, the `array_filter` function expects an array so you will need to check that the variable `$myArray[$index]["State"]` passed to the function is both set and also an array. This will remove the notices and warnings.

You can test for an array using the `is_array()` function and test if a variable is set using the `isset()` function.

In this example, an intermediate variable `$states_array` is set using data from your array. It checks if the original variable is valid, otherwise, it is set to an empty array. This is then passed into the `array_filter` function.

```
$states_array = (isset($myArray[$index]["State"]) && is_array($myArray[$index]["State"])) ? $myArray[$index]["State"] : array() ;
$states = array_values(array_filter($states_array));
```

You may also be interested to know that PHP 7 provides a null coalesce operator which may be helpful when handling variables that may or may not be set.

See:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

https://lornajane.net/posts/2015/new-in-php-7-null-coalesce-operator